# Word for trying to boost your image unnecessarily

Tags: synonyms, pejorative-language

A typical request where I have a word on the tip of my tongue that I just can't place.

UPDATED: A lot of the suggestions are direct synonyms of bragging so I'll try and clear up the context more.

The context that made me think of this word was an argument where one of the participants was spending a lot of time trying to sound intelligent or talk down to the other instead of resolving the issue, so some better examples of similar meanings might be

> "Get off of your high horse"

or

> "Stop going for the moral high-ground"

but in shorter form.

> "Stop singing your praises and get to the point"

Is another good example.

Context could be :

> "Enough of the **____**. Get to the point."

or in verb form

> "Stop ____ and get to the point".

EDIT: As in the comments, formal or slang suggestions accepted.

It could also be a more archaic term, something a King might say to a long-winded herald.

UPDATE:

Synonyms that are close to the right example:

- ensky
- adulate
- flatter
- commend
- glorify
- praise
- laud

These are good but I feel that something with more negative connotations would be better, or something describing a surplus of one of the above.

Other possible synonyms that don't quite fit:

http://thesaurus.com/browse/brag

- horn blowing
- showboating
- grandstanding
- narcissism
- ego-boosting
- ego-stroking
- pissing contest
- chest-beating
- self-promotion
- self-love
- double-speak

One strange example that came the closest was "brown-nosing". Is there a similar term that could be used for brown-nosing oneself so to speak?

Can't offer much else other than I think it's a Gerund, so ending in -ing.

Thanks for all the suggestions anyway.

Comment: Did you try "bragging synonym" http://thesaurus.com/browse/brag

Comment: I had a look but nothing really stuck out. I may be thinking of 'grandstanding' but I'm not sure how well that fits in this context

Comment: Do you want formal language or slang?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a more suitable formal term for it so slang examples may help. Any term for this sort of arrogant double-speak.

Comment: Some London slang: '*blowing smoke*', '*gassing*', and '*bullshiting*'.

Comment: If you already had a look and nothing really stuck out, then please do write down all the terms you already discarded. Otherwise people will post them all over again, wasting your time and theirs.

Comment: One word that may be apt in situations like the one you describe is _preening_. One definition of _preen_ is "to pride or congratulate (oneself) for achievement." The term has an element of boastfulness, an element of showing off, and an element of excessive self-admiration.

Comment: I agree that _preen_ could work well. What did you feel didn't quite work about _showboating_?

Comment: It feels like more of an action and applies more generally to showing off. It's also more shameless and likely to worsen your image whereas this case is an act that tries to benefit your image but at an inappropriate moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Pontificating* could work.

For more colloquial use, *Bluster* is appropriate.

*Big Talk* might also work

Answer (score 9):

*Enough of the* bloviating. *Get to the point.*

**[Bloviate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bloviate)** To discourse at length in a pompous or boastful manner: "the rural Babbitt who bloviates about 'progress' and 'growth'" (George Rebeck).

*It could also be a more archaic term, something a King might say to a long-winded herald*

> **[Magniloquent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magniloquent)**: speaking in or characterized by a high-flown often
>   bombastic style or manner
>
> **[Lexiphanic](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/236523/lexiphanic)**: using ostentatiously recondite words : bombastic, pretentiousLexiphanes (bombastic speaker in the dialogue Lexiphanes by
>   Lucian, 2d century A.D. Greek satirist)
>
> **[Ampullosity](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/430205/ampullosity)**: Turgidity or bombast

Answer (score 6):

Formal:

- Enough self-aggrandizing. Get to the point.
- Enough congratulating yourself. Get to the point.

Slang (this is what I might say personally):

- Enough big upping yourself. Get to the point.
- Enough congratulating yourself on your awesomeness. Get to the point.

Comment: Also slang: "patting yourself on the back." Even less formal: "Don't strain your shoulder patting yourself on the back. Get to the point."

Answer (score 4):

- Stop acting so ***self-important***, and get to the point.

> *The most usual form of monomania has commonly the same beginning as that from which Edgar Caswall suffered—an over-large idea of self-importance*

- Stop being so ***vainglorious***, get to the point.

> *He was an active, irritable, fuming, vainglorious little man, and elevated in his own opinion, by being the proxy of Mr. Astor.*
>    [Source](http://irving.thefreelibrary.com/Astoria-or-Anecdotes--of-an-enterprise-beyond-the-Rocky-Mountain/1-6#vainglorious)

> He was silent for a minute, ***casting about for the least vainglorious way*** in which to express himself.
>
> "Please don't think I'm bragging," he began. "I don't intend it that way at all. But I have a feeling that I am what I may call a natural student. I can study by myself. I take to it kindly, like a duck to water. You see yourself what I did with grammar. And I've learned much of other things - you would never dream how much. And I'm only getting started."
>   [source](http://london.thefreelibrary.com/Martin-Eden/10-1#vainglorious)

- Enough of your ***patronizing***. Get to the point.
- Stop *patronising* me. Get to the point.
- Stop being so *patronising*, get to the point.

> She was furious. What right had Lord Dawlish to look down his nose and
>   murmur '*Noblesse oblige*' when she asked him a question, as if she had
>   suggested that he should commit some crime? **It was the patronizing way**
>   he had said it that infuriated her, as if he were a superior being of
>   some kind, governed by codes which she could not be expected to
>   understand.
>   [Source](http://wodehouse.thefreelibrary.com/Uneasy-Money/3-1#patronizing)

Comment: +1 Patronizing's probably what OP's getting at, if not some manner of **condescend**.

Comment: It fits the context but patronizing implies more of a negative effect on the other person than a positive effect on the speaker. Something along the lines of 'patronizing to help validate one's argument' would be better

Answer (score 3):

I’m having trouble figuring out what you’re going for, since you have ruled out so many promising possibilities, but here are a few:

- [patting yourself on the back](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/pat-yourself-on-the-back), which means [*boasting*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boast?&o=100074&s=t) (similar to “self-aggrandizing” and “congratulating yourself”, which were in [the first answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/180341/26083)).
- “inflating”, which can mean [aggrandizing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inflate) or [puffing up with pride](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inflate?s=t).
- [puffery](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/puffery) -- Flattering, often exaggerated praise and publicity, especially when used for promotional purposes.
- “rambling”, which can mean [lengthy and digressive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rambling) or [confused or inconsequential](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rambling?q=rambling) (as an adjective, in reference to speech or writing; it can also [be interpreted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ramble) [as a gerund](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ramble?q=ramble)), so this satisfies only half of what you’re asking for.

---

I suspect that I’m getting further away from what you want, but I’ll offer these phrases for your consideration:

- Beating around the bush
- Begging the question
- Dodging the question
- Ducking the question

Comment: To be clear I am looking for a specific word. If I can't find it even with a bounty then I'll be happy to accept the answer with the most suitable alternatives. It's useful to have all these possibilities anyway. Puffery would be a good choice as an alternative to a Gerund form like my word may be.

Answer (score 3):

**Blathering** looks like it might encompass the spectrum of your requirements: it describes unnecessarily excessive speech which nobody cares to hear (except perhaps the speaker). It fits perfectly into your context example, and even sounds a bit archaic to me. It doesn't necessarily connote bragging, but a lot of unimportant braggery could be called blather.

Comment: It is a good example but as you mentioned it doesn't have the right connotations. I'd use this for more generic sort of filler speech but the word I'm looking for is more specific. "Blathering with the purpose of promoting yourself" would be a possible definition.

Comment: … or “self-serving blathering”?

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking Highfalutin. A highfalutin person thinks much of themselves.

Comment: That works as an adjective, but not as a verb or a noun (which is what the questioner seems to be after, judging from their examples).

Comment: You can tell someone to "Stop your highfalutin". It's not grammatically correct, but it is common parlance.

Comment: My sense of this adjective (and OED agrees) is that it can only really modify some type of *discourse,* as in highfalutin *praise.*

Answer (score 2):

> Stop **flexing** and get to the point.

With this usage the reader/listener has to intuit that *flexing* is being used metaphorically to liken bantering in highfalutin terms to tightening a muscle just to see how big it is—both of which are acts of idleness and vanity.  To ask for less of an intuitive jump from the reader/listener, you could extend the phrasing to:

- *flexing your intellect*
- *flexing your vocabulary*
- *flexing your education*
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well this fits

**big-noting**

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/big-note

> Boastfully exaggerate one’s own wealth or importance:
>    *he’s continually trying to big-note himself*

but apparently it's only Australia/NZ.

I also like

**ballyhoo**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ballyhoo

> a clamorous and vigorous attempt to win customers or advance any cause; blatant advertising or publicity.

but it's of 19th US origin, so not really kingly either.

Answer (score 1):

**hyperbole**

*"Enough of the hyperbole. Get to the point."*

> 1. obvious and intentional exaggeration.

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hyperbole

Comment: I don't think this communicates the about-oneselfness that the question suggests. It also means deliberate exaggeration which is not necessarily the case either here.

Answer (score 1):

First thought that comes to my mind is "stop BS-ing."

Answer (score 1):

I really like kollosus' suggetion of *pontificating*.

A couple of others along those lines, though not all are single words:

*Get off your soapbox*

Stop *lecturing*

*Get over yourself*

Answer (score 1):

I would say a person like that is *putting on airs*.

Answer (score 1):

- "Don't be so **egotistical**",
- "You're an **egomaniac**"

Answer (score 0):

Stop "up-voting" yourself and get to the point.

Answer (score 0):

How about, ***Stop blowing smoke***?

blow smoke  (American)
to say things that are not true in order to make yourself or something you are involved with seem better than it is The team put on an unbelievable performance. I'm not just blowing smoke - they were great.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+smoke